# Chi Test to compare the volume distributions of 2 samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test

I have 2 samples and i want to check whether their distributions are similar (or not).

The samples are distributed in the following way (they are banded into 'scores'):

[image: Volume Distributions of Pop1 and Pop2]

How do i check the whether the distributions of Population1 and population2 are the same?

Do i do a chi-test?

If so, how do i calculate the obs vs expected frequencies?

Comment: The nature of your data is not clear. Is "score range" a categorical variable? Are the values listed under Population counts?

Comment: Hi Sal, i shall do my best to clarify. The every observation in my dataset has a 'score' (specifically, this is a credit score) and the score range divides these scores up into bands. And yes, the values are the number of observations that fall into that particular score band

Comment: With this data and your question, you could use a chi-square test of association.  For this, you can get the expected frequencies by hand, but it easier to do with software.  You'll have to find a procedure in a textbook, or use (free) software such as R. In R, an example is here,  http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_04.html . In R,  for the expected counts, add a *$expected* after the last parenthesis in the *chisq.test* call.

Comment: However, because your ranges are really ordinal in nature, not categorical in nature, I would use a test that takes advantage of this.  You might use Mann-Whitney test, or a median test.  These tell you, essentially, if one population has higher scores than the other, not just if their distributions are different.  With these tests and similar tests, be sure you understand the null and alternative hypotheses.